How can I create a list based on values from all columns?
I would like to create lists, such as in df2, from data such as in df1.  Most of the help I read online is about the opposite, how to dissect lists.  In the end, I would like this list to be accessible as a new column in the original df1.
import pandas as pd
    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9])), 
                   columns=['numbers', 'numbers2', 'numbers3'])
    
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip([[1,4,7], [2,5,8], [3,6,9]])), 
                   columns=['list_of_numbers'])

Thanks for taking a look.  Please let me know if you have any questions if my example is not clear.


You can use df.apply on axis=1 and assign to a new column with df.assign:
df2 = df1.assign(list_of_numbers=df1.apply(list, axis=1))

df2

   numbers  numbers2  numbers3 list_of_numbers
0        1         4         7       [1, 4, 7]
1        2         5         8       [2, 5, 8]
2        3         6         9       [3, 6, 9]

Or add to existing df1:
df1['list_of_numbers'] = df1.apply(list, axis=1)


Convert to_numpy, then tolist:
df1['list_of_numbers'] = df1.to_numpy().tolist()

Or, for a new DataFrame:
out = df1.assign(list_of_numbers=df1.to_numpy().tolist())

Output:
   numbers  numbers2  numbers3 list_of_numbers
0        1         4         7       [1, 4, 7]
1        2         5         8       [2, 5, 8]
2        3         6         9       [3, 6, 9]

Timings
On 300K rows and 3 columns
# df1.assign(list_of_numbers=df1.to_numpy().tolist())
44 ms ± 2.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# df1.assign(list_of_numbers=df1.apply(list, axis=1))
1.28 s ± 15.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

